# QT 5.6.1 app crashes after exiting slot only on x86 arch but not x64

Tags: c++, windows, qt, x86

I am facing an issue that i cannot understand and i need your lights. I have found no answers on my problem on others topics yet.

### Context :

- I am using QT 5.6.1 compiled dynamically (x86 and x64) on a Windows 10 x64.

### Problem :

I have made a basic program compiled twice (x86 and x64) that just display a Window with a button and connects the button to the "clicked" signal. My Window is correctly displayed but when i hit my button to fire signal the app crashed just after exiting the SLOT connected to the SIGNAL (qDebug is correctly called from the slot). But i am only facing this issue with x86 QT dll's...

### Here is the code:

**.cpp:**

```
MyWidget::MyWidget()
{
    QMainWindow *pqMainWindow= new QMainWindow(this);
    QPushButton *pqButton= new QPushButton("MyButton");
    /* Setting up the window */
    pqMainWindow->setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModal);
    pqMainWindow->setGeometry(geometry());
    pqMainWindow->move(QPoint(100, 100));
    /* Connecting signal clicked to slot */
    QObject::connect(pqButton, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(_onMyActionTriggered(bool)));    
    pqMainWindow->setCentralWidget(pqButton);
    /* Showing the window */
    pqMainWindow->show();
}
MyWidget::~MyWidget()
{
    /* Nothing to do yet */
}
void MyWidget::_onMyActionTriggered(bool bValue)
{
    qDebug("Slot <_onMyActionTriggered> called");
}
int __cdecl main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    QApplication qapp(argc, argv);
    MyWidget widget;
    return qapp.exec();
}
```

**.h**

```
class MyWidget: public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT;
    public:
        MyWidget();
        virtual ~MyWidget();
    private slots:
        void _onMyActionTriggered(bool bValue);
    private:
};
```

### Here is the call trace :

```
Qt5Widgets!QAction::activate+0x103
Qt5Widgets!QToolButton::nextCheckState+0x1a
Qt5Widgets!QAbstractButton::click+0x103
Qt5Widgets!QAbstractButton::mouseReleaseEvent+0x7e
Qt5Widgets!QToolButton::mouseReleaseEvent+0xd
Qt5Widgets!QWidget::event+0xa8
Qt5Widgets!QSizePolicy::QSizePolicy+0x83b
Qt5Core!QCoreApplication::translate+0x30f56
Qt5Gui!QGuiApplicationPrivate::processMouseEvent+0x6c1
USER32!SetManipulationInputTarget+0x53
USER32!DispatchMessageW+0x251
USER32!DispatchMessageW+0x10
qwindows!qt_plugin_query_metadata+0x2065
Qt5Core!QCoreApplication::exec+0x160
qt_auth_test!wmain+0x7c
qt_auth_test!QObject::event+0xb5
KERNEL32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x24
ntdll!RtlUnicodeStringToInteger+0x21e
ntdll!RtlCaptureContext+0xe1
```

I have compiled QT myself but i have the same result when using dll and lib downloaded on QT Website.

Comment: The slot name in the header doesn't match the one in the source.

Comment: `qapp(i, NULL);` - this is wrong. You should pass arguments from `main`

Comment: @owacoder i have changed the slot name in the post. Edited, thx ;)

Comment: @DmitrySazonov it does not change anything but thanks for this advice.

Comment: "it does not change anything but thanks for this advice" Oooh, it changes everything because `QCoreApplication` tries to extract the application name from the arguments. Calling that constructor without `argv` pointing to at least one valid C string is undefined behavior. You shouldn't implement a `_tmain`, Qt does it for you already. Put your code into a regular `main`.

Comment: @KubaOber "it does not change anything" means that i have the same crash passing the args from main but you and Dmitry are absolutely right, i am not doing it correctly and i have changed that ;) thank you for this very clear explanation.

Comment: You're not helping yourself by stacking even *more* undefined behavior on top of whatever problem you already have... "i have changed that" No, you didn't. Make sure your question matches your code, and ideally add the `.ui` to the question - but minimize it first, remove anything in the .ui file that doesn't change the behavior! Heck, perhaps you don't even need the .ui and can create the widget programmatically in a few lines. Minimize!

Comment: I highly suggest to start with the basics: implement a `main`, not `_tmain`, initialize the application instance *properly*, create a simple widget with a single action manually. Keep it as small as possible. If it doesn't work: great, you have nailed it on a much smaller problem. If it works: perfect, now keep adding code until you break it.

Comment: @KubaOber Thank you. I am new to StackOverflow: i will edit my post with the changes i have made from your advices. Sorry for that... I did not add the ui file because i did not wanted to make an unreadable long post. I will build my window step by step programatically. Once again, thanks ;)

Comment: The approach you should take has nothing to do with stackoverflow. Minimization is a basic technique of bug hunting.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115855/discussion-between-jaydee-and-kuba-ober).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks everyone for your help, i've finally found the issue.

**Here is the answer :**

My program uses the stdcall (/Gz) convention but QT uses cdecl (/Gd). The generated moc file was compiled with the stdcall convention and this is what caused the issue (stack problem when releasing parameters because of different convention between callee and caller).
Now my program is compiled using the stdcall convention (because it is mandatory for me) BUT the generated moc files are compiled with cdecl and i have set the __cdecl keyword on my private slots headers! Now It works perfectly!

Once again, thank for your time. I hope this topic will help someone one day with a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Setting window modality on a child of a hidden widget makes no sense. Perhaps that's a problem. Try the following, and check if/when it crashes. There definitely is a Qt 5.6 bug on OS X at least: when the button's modality is reverted, the widget still doesn't receive input and you must exit the application by other means.

```
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
   int n = 0;
   QApplication app{argc, argv};
   QPushButton widget{"Widget"};
   QPushButton button{"Button", &widget};
   button.setWindowFlags(Qt::Window);

   QObject::connect(&button, &QPushButton::clicked, [&]{
      button.setText(button.text().append("."));
      ++n;
      if (n == 5) {
         button.setWindowModality(Qt::WindowModal);
         button.hide();
         button.show();
      }
      else if (n == 10) {
         button.setWindowModality(Qt::NonModal);
         button.hide();
         button.show();
      }
      else if (n == 15)
         app.quit();
   });

   button.move(widget.geometry().bottomRight());
   widget.show();
   button.show();
   return app.exec();
}
```